# comparing a Node and an Object with a BST data structure

Tags: java, object, compare, compareto

I'm getting a "java.lang.string cannot be cast to node" exception. I thought of converting the localRoot to a string using a provided toString method then comparing them, nut this leaves no concept of 'greater than' or 'less than' which I need to navigate the BST...

```
 int computeResult = ((Node<E>)o).compareTo(localRoot);
```

where 
o is of type Object
localRoot is of type Node
compareTo method takes a Node

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I spent some time this weekend working on a [Java binary tree implementation](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/10/practice-practice-practice.html).  See what you think of it.

Answer (score 0):

String does have a compareTo method that does have a concept of greater than and less than

So you could write that line of code as:

```
int computeResult = o.toString().compareTo(localRoot.toString());
```

From The Javadocs for java.lang.string:

> `public int compareTo(String  anotherString)`
>
> Specified by: compareTo in interface
>   Comparable
>
> Parameters: anotherString - the String
>   to be compared.
>
> Returns: the value 0 if the argument
>   string is equal to this string; a
>   value less than 0 if this string is
>   lexicographically less than the string
>   argument; and a value greater than 0
>   if this string is lexicographically
>   greater than the string argument.